# Is "Ich gehe nach Kartoffeln" correct?

Tags: grammar

Wenn ich z.B. zum Essen Kartoffeln machen will und die Kartoffeln sind im Keller, sage ich dann:

> Ich gehe in den Keller **nach** Kartoffeln.

Kann man "nach" verwenden oder muss da ein anderes Wort hin?

Comment: German does not have a phrasing like "I go to the basement for potatoes". And generally of all origin-prepositions there are, "nach" is usually the worst choice unless you talk about countries and such

Comment: My first reaction would be *Nach Kartoffeln was...?*

Comment: This is an *awesome* question! Rationally, I'd agree with everybody else that this is wrong, but somehow, I have a gut feeling that it is possible after all - no idea why yet. Perhaps it's the similarity to "nach etw. sehen" or the parallel construction to the English "for". But it *does* sound idiomatic, if very unusual... I'm stumped. *x-files music*

Comment: 1. Reaktion: Merkwuerdige Ortsnamen gibt es. 2. Reaktion: Ach, das ist damit gemeint. 3. Reaktion: Stimmt, irgendwie klingt es gar nicht so falsch. Vielleicht liegt das daran, wie schon von Thorsten Dittmar erwaehnt, dass etwas der Art "Ich gehe in den Keller nach Kartoffeln [schauen]" moeglich waere...?

Comment: Standarddeutsch ist das nicht. In irgendeinem Dialekt könnte das schon vorkommen.

Comment: Wenn die Bäurin Kartoffeln hacken geht, sagt sie in vielen Gegenden "Ich gehe *in die* Kartoffeln".

Answer (score 7):

Neben die üblichen Konstruktionen mit einem zweiten Verb

```
Ich gehe in den Keller und hole Kartoffeln (hoch).
```

Wie von user5163 vorgeschlagen, oder

```
Ich gehe in den Keller, um Kartoffeln zu holen.
```

wie von 949, wahlweise:

```
Ich gehe in den Keller, Kartoffeln holen.
```

ginge, ohne weiteres Verb, "wegen der":

```
Ich gehe in den Keller wegen der Kartoffeln.
```

"Nach den Kartoffeln" klingt für mich schlesisch/ostpreußisch, aber ich bin da nicht sicher.

Comment: In example 3, are you sure about the comma?

Comment: Nein, bei Kommas bin ich meist sehr unsicher und freue mich über sachkundige Korrekturen. Ich dachte Teil 1 sei ein vollwertiger Hauptsatz, und Teil 2 ist ...? Eher hätte ich gedacht in Satz 2 muss es weg, weil da das "um" verbindet.

Comment: ne, in 2 muss es definitiv stehen, da der zweite Teil ein vollertiger Nebensatz ist. Ich stell für das andere mal eine Frage hier

Comment: "Ich gehe in den Elsass nach Metz" wäre übrigens vom Satzbau wie in der Frage, aber mit ganz anderer Bedeutung. Einen Deut näher wäre "Ich gehe in den Keller nach Susi (die geht sofort, ich erst in 5 Minuten)" aber auch nur weil die Bedeutung eine ganz andere ist.

Answer (score 3):

Auch wenn die Konstruktion mit "nach" nicht grammatikalisch korrekt ist, verstehe ich den Satz so, dass schon für das Gehen eine Absicht ausgedrückt werden soll. Das würde ich so ausdrücken:

> Ich gehe in den Keller, um Kartoffeln zu holen.

Eine Präposition, mit der so etwas ausdrückbar wäre, gibt es leider nicht. Grammatikalisch in Ordnung wäre "für", allerdings klingt das komisch bzw. mehr danach, dass man damit den Kartoffeln einen Gefallen tut (und nicht sich selbst, indem man Kartoffeln holt).

Answer (score 2):

"Ich gehe nach Kartoffeln" - ich meine, das ist kein richtiges Deutsch. Das hört sich an als hätte jemand English I'm going for potatoes Wort für Wort übersetzt. Meine Formulierung wäre:
Ich geh mal in den Keller Kartoffeln holen.

Answer (score 2):

Meine Oma (übrigens auch aus Ostpreußen) sagte immer:

> Ich werde noch ins Dorf *nach Brot* gehen.

Außerdem fuhren sie noch “nach dem Westen” und ich schätze mal, meine Urgroßeltern fuhren noch "nach den Fidschi-Inseln” (Lied von Willi Forst).

Answer (score 2):

Die Konstruktion "nach etwas gehen" war einst tatsächlich eine gebräuchliche Umschreibung für "etwas holen". So schreibt Adelung in seinem "Grammatisch-kritischen Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart" von 1811:

> In engerer Bedeutung wird dieses Vorwort besonders in der vertraulichen Sprechart sehr häufig gebraucht, wenn die Richtung der Bewegung in der Absicht geschiehet, um die Person oder Sache nach welcher sie gerichtet ist, herbey zu hohlen, oder zu bekommen. Es ist schon jemand nach Wein gegangen, um Wein zu hohlen. Ich will nach Veilchen gehen, Gell. um Veilchen zu suchen. <sup>[Quelle](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009133_2_0_20)</sup>

und

> Nach Veilchen gehen, hingehen und Veilchen hohlen wollen. <sup>[Quelle](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009132_2_0_858)</sup>

Auch im Deutschen Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm wird die Wendung erwähnt:

> [nach] *Bei den verben* gehen, laufen, schicken, senden *u. s. w. mit dem nebenbegriffe des herbeiholens: mhd.* <sup>[Quelle](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN00071#XGN00071)</sup>

Heutzutage ist sie hingegen völlig außer Gebrauch geraten und wird, wie man an den Antworten und Kommentaren hier sieht, oft sogar als falsch empfunden. Duden und Wiktionary führen sie nicht einmal als "veraltet".

Als einen *relativ* aktuellen Beleg kann ich noch [diesen Zeitzeugen-Bericht](http://www.harryw.de/?page_id=217) anbieten, verfaßt nach 1976 von einem damals mindestens 70-jährigen Niederschlesier. Darin heißt es:

> Und bei dem Bauer Striebing ... haben wir Kartoffeln geholt – gestohlen! ... Striebing hatte einen scharfen Hofhund frei herum laufen, so mußten wir dann **nach Kartoffeln gehen**, wenn der Wind vom Hunde herkam.

Das paßt interessanterweise auch zu der schon von "user unknown" in seiner Antwort geäußerten Vermutung, die Wendung könne im ostpreußischen oder schlesischen Sprachgebrauch üblich sein.

Answer (score 1):

„Nach“ kann man dort nicht verwenden, weil „Kartoffeln“ kein Ort ist.

Bessere Beispiele:

> Ich gehe in den Keller zu den Kartoffeln.

oder

> Ich gehe in den Keller und hole Kartoffeln (hoch).

Comment: Umgangssprachlich hört man *"ich gehe nach..."* in manchen Gegenden schon.

Comment: Die Begründung ist falsch, vgl. "Ich strebe nach Glück."

Comment: "Ich gehe nach …" kommt durch aus vor, aber dannach kommt (IMHO) immer ein Ort.
"Ich strebe nach Glück." kommt auch vor. "Ich gehe nach Glück." aber nicht.

Comment: Ich meine von einem schlesischen Schriftsteller schon mal etwas ähnliches gehört zu haben, wie "nach den Kartoffeln gehen", weiß aber nicht mehr was es war. "Zu den Kartoffeln" klingt, als wolltest Du da bleiben - keiner versteht Dich, außer die Kartoffeln. :)

Comment: @Ingo aber 'streben' ist ein anderes Verb, du gehst doch nicht nach Glück ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Kann man "nach" verwenden oder muss da ein anderes Wort hin?

You can, **but** (as hinted already) it requires an infinitive of a verb and only some verbs are possible, e. g.

> Ich gehe in den Keller, nach Kartoffeln **schauen**.

Note that this is more frequently used when you are

- either not sure, whether there are still potatoes in the basement
- going to check their condition (as in whether they germinate already)

The second case is quite common. You'd use use it rather, when you e. g. cooking potatoes

> Ich gehe in **die Küche**, nach **den** Kartoffeln schauen.

That implicates, that you are frying or cooking potatoes and you are going to check, whether they are done.

If someone is going to fetch potatoes from the basement, you rather'd hear him say

> Ich gehe in den Keller, Kartoffeln holen.
>   *equivalent to*
>   Ich gehe in den Keller, um Kartoffeln zu holen.

Here **fetching potatoes is the reason** he actually goes there.

---

If that guy was intending to go down to the basement *anyway*, he might say

> Ich gehe [ohnehin/sowieso] in den Keller und bringe Kartoffeln mit.

more common you'd hear

> Ich bringe Kartoffeln mit, da ich [ohnehin/sowieso] in den Keller gehe.
>   Da ich [ohnehin/sowieso] in den Keller gehe, kann ich Kartoffeln mitbringen.

or

> Ich bringe Kartoffeln mit, wenn ich in den Keller gehe.
>   Wenn ich in den Keller gehe, ich bringe Kartoffeln mit.

The emphasized part is always the first clause.

Answer (score 0):

"Nach" kann nicht verwendet werden.

"gehen nach" hat folgende Bedeutungen:

- an einen **bestimmten, benannten Ort** gehen. Häufig gebraucht im Sinne von "ich ziehe nach":

> Ich gehe nach München.

- in der **Reihenfolge als nächstes** gehen:

> Ich gehe nach Karin zum Geldautomaten.

- Bei Uhren: Eine **falsche Zeit in der Vergangenheit** anzeigen:

> Die Uhr geht nach.